# continously change UIView background color

Tags: iphone

I am new to iphone dev and in the process of reading Apress.Beginning.Iphone4.Dev, don't know if this is the fastest way to become good in developing iphone apps.
    Well I am currently in chapter 4 , I have finished implementing the sample code, but I want to add a little mod.

- button called disco
- if pressed, Touch Up Inside , will start changing 
  `self.view.backgroundColor` values randomly 100 times 
  in a for loop.

  My problem is the background only changes after the IBAction connected to the button
  disco, finished, so I could only see one color change instead of at least 2 color changes.

my suspicion is that, the view does not get refreshed / reloaded until the IBAction is completed , is this suspicion correct ?

is it possible to achieve the feature I wish to implements, 
- touch a button
- background color changes randomly for 100 times.

Thank you in Advance and sorry for the newb question.
timex88

========================

Thank you all, I got this working thanks to your pointers. but instead of 100 times,
I let the `changeBgColor` method run indefinitely.

What i noticed was, while the `changeBgColor` still runs, if I were to touch the disco 
button again, the rate of `changeBgColor` method being executed became higher, can someone please explain the reason ?

Thanks again
timex 88

Answer (score 1):

```
- (IBAction)changeColor:(id)sender
{
  if (_timer == nil)
  {
    _changeColorCount = 0;
    _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2 
                                              target:self 
                                            selector:@selector(colorTimerFired) 
                                            userInfo:nil 
                                             repeats:YES];
  }
}

- (void)colorTimerFired
{
    if (_changeColorCount > 100)
    {
        [_timer invalidate];
        _timer = nil;
    }
    else
    {
         [view setBackgroundColor:newRandomColor];
         _changeColorCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry since I am a newb , I would like to confirm , in your code above , how and where is _timer declared ? , thanks again.

Comment: The _timer is the instance variable, so you need to declare it in your @interface section.

Comment: You need to declare it in your @interface section: NSTimer* _timer;. There timer will call colorTimerFired method every 0.2 seconds, so the view colour will change 5 times a second in this example. After 100 times you stop the timer by calling [_timer invalidate], which removes it from the runloop. Also, you nullify the pointer, so next time you press the button you can run another timer.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color in a  method & call this method using NSTimer.set Repeats for NSTimer as YES.Then your method will be called again & again

Answer (score 0):

on disco button click write below code

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 
                                                  target:self 
                                                selector:@selector(changeColor)  
                                                userInfo:nil 
                                                 repeats:YES];
```

now make a new method as below,
declare `int i` in `.h` file and initialize in `viewDidLoad` with 0.

```
- (void) changeColor
{
   // code for color change;
   i++;
   if (i==100)
   {
     [timer invalidate];
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks but the should the NSTimer declaration be a pointer, NSTimer *timer = [[NSTimer alloc] ......]; , because using your code verbatim , caused compilation error " Invalid initializer "

Comment: yes i forgot that but do it.... i m editing that ...... and please keep accepting the answers...

Comment: hmm sorry , did I closed the question ? did not realized it

Comment: I mean that if you find the answer correct then please teak mark or upvote to the answer...